# How to implement a custom cursor component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, event-handling, react-hooks, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make a custom cursor component in react, based on this article: https://dev.to/andrewchmr/awesome-animated-cursor-with-react-hooks-5ec3

I'm using react router dom, and the problem is that the hover events are only working on the content within the router components on initial page load, or after refreshing the pages.

The hover is however always working on the nav component links. I've set up a basic CodeSandbox where you can see how the hover works on the nav links, but not on the page content links (after initial page load and when navigating between pages).

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-newton-u9hk5

I'm a beginner with react, so I'm sure I'm going about this the wrong away. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that when the route changes, your **Cursor Component** does not need to be updated, therefore the useEffect hook is not called. And that's why your listeners are not attached to new anchor tags that appear when you change the route.

However, React Router Dom has introduced a new hook called **useLocation** that you can use to respond to the route change. This hook returns current url, so when you pass it to the array as below, **useEffect** will be called everytime when the url changes, therefore it will attach your listeners to the recently rendered anchor tags

Add this to your Cursor component:

```js
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

// then in your functional component

  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    addEventListeners();
    handleLinkHoverEvents();
    return () => removeEventListeners();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [location]);
```

Comment: Yes! That did the trick. Thanks so much for your help.